# How to define a custom cross-platform size_t type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03, size-t, size-type

[`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is commonly used for array indexing and loop counting. By definition, [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator as well as the `sizeof...` operator and the `alignof` operator (since C++11). It's defined in the following headers:

- `<cstddef>`
- `<cstdio>`
- `<cstdlib>`
- `<cstring>`
- `<ctime>`
- `<cwchar>`

To my understanding, the type returned by these operators is implementation-deﬁned.

What I want is to define a custom `size_t` in order to avoid pulling unnecessary stuff from any of the headers mentioned above in a `.cpp` file of mine, since in my file I only need `std::size_t`.

In C++11 and above, I thought I could use the following alias:

```
using size_t = decltype(sizeof(1));
```

However, I'd like to define a `size_t` type for pre-C++11 compilers in a portable/cross-platform way.

So is there a portable way to define `size_t` for pre-C++11?

Comment: You should probably tag this question C++03 or C++98, but not C++11, right?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to include any of the standard header files? They are usually not that big and won't impact compilation time noticeably. And as the ones where `size_t` is defined doesn't really have any functions definitions in them that means there wont be any code generated for them either. Can you please elaborate on the *actual* problem you want to solve by defining your own type like that?

Comment: `cstddef` is a pretty small header, in terms of symbols that is. Is it really too much namespace pollution to pull it in?

Comment: You could remake [`boost::typeof`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/typeof.html)

Comment: does defining a custom type saves you from including a header that contains the standard definition? anyway any standard container types have `size_type` that you can use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well theoretically, if listing of all possible (unsigned) candidates for `size_t` doesn't bother you, you could make use of SFINAE:

```
template <class T, class N = void, bool = sizeof(T) == sizeof(sizeof(T))>
struct TL { 
    typedef typename N::type type;
};

template <class T, class N>
struct TL<T, N, true> {
    typedef T type;
};

typedef TL<unsigned short,TL<unsigned int, TL<unsigned long, TL<unsigned long long> > > >::type SizeT;
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jPuV5FKBGrGQgwIv)

---

**Edit:**

Workaround for compilers which differentiate `unsigned long` from `unsigned long long` despite the fact that they're assuming `sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(unsigned long long)`:

```
template <class U>
U *declptrval(U);

template <class U>
char is_exact(U *);

template <class U>
short is_exact(...);

template <class T, class N = void, bool = sizeof(is_exact<T>(declptrval(sizeof(T))))==sizeof(char)>
struct TL { 
    typedef typename N::type type;
};

template <class T, class N>
struct TL<T, N, true> {
    typedef T type;
};

typedef TL<unsigned short,TL<unsigned int, TL<unsigned long, TL<unsigned long long> > > >::type SizeT;
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tFSXZhCr6sZrMK7y)

Comment: Dude what kind of sorcery is this?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: @101010 You can call me Houdini ;)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you've listed the only two cross-platform ways to get `size_t`: Include the definition from standard header, or decltype (since C++11). But both are explicitly unavailable to you.

The third option is manual porting i.e. use pre-defined macros to detect the environment, and choose the correct typedef from a manually maintained list of typedefs. For example, on GCC you might use [`__SIZE_TYPE__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) (however, consider the warning in the documentation that the macro should not be used directly and that it is not provided on all platforms). On other compilers you would use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, "implementation-defined" includes the header files, not just the compiler itself.  If you look at [[expr.sizeof]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof), they seem to suggest just using this:

```
#include <cstddef>
```

Comment: I know.  I am just pointing out that the C++ standards are a bit weird in that they don't require that built-in language features (like sizeof and [typeid](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid)) necessarily be backed by built-in types (that don't need includes).